# Streaming de arquivos por HTTP em Node

Tags: node.js, http, upload, download, streaming

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um sistema no qual uma das partes fundamentais é transmitir um arquivo via Node JS.
Suponha que eu tenho uma **conexão A**, essa conexão está realizando o upload de um arquivo via HTTP.
E também há uma **conexão B**, essa conexão quer baixar o arquivo que a **conexão A** está enviando, também via HTTP.
Todas as soluções que eu achei consistem em esperar a **conexão A** terminar seu upload por completo, para que depois a **conexão B** possa baixar o arquivo. Isso não é de grande ajuda, pois em arquivos grandes essa transferencia duraria muito tempo.
Há algum modo de fazer streaming desse arquivo, para que a **conexão B** vá baixando o arquivo a medida que ele é upado pela **conexão A**? Se sim, gostaria de saber como.